# How to convert macros for Arduino code?

Tags: c

I have a piece of code I'd like to make Arduino editor friendly. The code is written in C and contains macros the Arduino IDE can't deal with. Is it a good idea to turn those macros into functions?

```
#define AN221_EXECUTE_Low   cbi(PORTA, PIN0)        //drive EXECUTE low
#define AN221_PORb_High     sbi(PORTA, PIN1)        //drive PORb high
#define AN221_ACTIVATE      bit_is_set(PINA, PIN2)      //sense ACTIVATE high
#define AN221_NO_ERROR      bit_is_set(PINA, PIN3)      //sense ERRb high i.e. no rror
#define AN221_ERRb_Input    outp(0xEB, DDRA)        //make uP drive ERRb
#define AN221_ERRb_Output   outp(0xE3, DDRA)        //make uP sense ERRb
```

Comment: Compiled ok for me - what were you expecting and what actually happened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it a good idea to turn those macros into functions?

it depends.

macros are fast, but lack type checking.

functions offer type checking but incur overhead.

whether one is better than the other depends on your priorities.